# What is the difference between running docker exec in terminal and in bash script

Tags: bash, docker

Let's assume I run the following command inside a script:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

docker run --name mydb --rm -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=kgalli -e POSTGRES_USER=kgalli -p "9999:5432" -v $PWD/db:/opt -d postgres
```

When I then run the following command to create a database it works fine.

```
docker exec -e PGPASSWORD=kgalli mydb psql -U kgalli -d template1 -c "CREATE DATABASE kgalli_test WITH OWNER kgalli ENCODING 'UTF8' LC_COLLATE = 'en_US.utf8' LC_CTYPE = 'en_US.utf8';"
```

However when I add this line to the script above, so the script not only starts the postgres server but also creates the database it fails.

I do not really understand why I get the following error:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I know I can instruct docker postgres image to create a database on start. But this is actually not what I want to achieve. I just using this as an example to understand the problem.

Comment: If you are running `docker exec` immediately after `docker run`, the Psql server instance propably hasn't finished initializing yet.

Comment: Of course that is the issue. Thanks I will use a wait script to wait for the postgres to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're running it in a script, it's most likely just happening too quickly. The `docker run …` command returns immediately, and then `docker exec …` is attempting to use PostgreSQL while the database server is still starting up. You need to wait for it to be ready before creating the extra database.

That said, the [postgres image](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/) has functionality in its entrypoint script to run custom initialization scripts. You can put your `CREATE DATABASE …` statement into a `.sql` file or config and mount it into `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` in the container. The postgres container will automatically run it when the database server is ready.

The docs for this seems to have disappeared, but [you can see the implementation in docker-entrypoint.sh](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/45b855af13f6a753fa77bb830c482af6a69d50da/11/docker-entrypoint.sh#L145).

Answer (score 1):

Using `docker run`, you are starting a new container, using `docker exec`, you are executing a command in already running container

Comment: I know what the commands are used for. My question is why is the docker exec command working when I execute is from a terminal but not when i execute it in the bash shell script.

Answer (score 0):

The `docker run` command first `creates` a writeable container layer over the specified image, and then `starts` it using the specified command.

The `docker exec` command runs a new command in a running container.
If the container is paused, then the `docker exec` command will fail with an error

```
$ docker pause test

test

$ docker ps

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                   PORTS               NAMES
1ae3b36715d2        ubuntu:latest       "bash"              17 seconds ago      Up 16 seconds (Paused)                       test

$ docker exec test ls

FATA[0000] Error response from daemon: Container test is paused, unpause the container before exec

$ echo $?
1
```

([ref.1](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/))
([ref.2](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/))

Comment: Ok but I do not pause the container run. So why should this be related to my issue. Can you please elaborate?